# Receiving null values of object in web api from HttpClient.post of angular 4

Tags: angular, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-services

I am having the problem will posting data to my web api from my angular 2 application. I am new to angular 2 as when I am posting the data to web API and place a debugger in web API the request reaches but all the values remains null. I am beating my head from last 2 days and still not able to find the error why i am not getting the values of object in web API.

**Code from Web API:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostEmployee")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
public IHttpActionResult PostEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Employees.Add(employee);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(employee);
    //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.Id }, employee);
}
```

**Model from Web Api:**

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactPreference { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

**Model in TypeScript**

```
export class Employee 
{
    Id : number;
    FullName: string;
    Email: string;
    PhoneNumber: string;
    ContactPreference: string;
    Gender: string;   
    DepartmentId: number;
    DateOfBirth?: Date;
    Photo:string;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

**Code From my Angular 2 Application employee.service.ts**

```
 createEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    let _headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: _headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify(employee);

    return this._http.post(API_URL + '/api/Employees/PostEmployee', body, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

I am attaching the image of web API in debugger mode will catching the request
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHn3g.jpg)

Please help me in this Solution. Thanks.

Comment: **Sorry Guys its Http.post**

Comment: Do I know why you are stringifying the employee object (JSON.stringify(employee))?

Comment: @VithuBati i am using this to convert object to json and pass it. If i remove json.stringify then the behaviour remains the same as i discussed